# Router.use require a middleware but got undefined

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make routes in different folder and then access them in my main app.js Here is my both of the files.

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const {router, users} = require("./routers/routers");

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.send("Home Page");
})

app.use("/users", users);

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("Server Started");
})
```

routers.js

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const users = router.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Route Created");
})

module.exports = {router, users};
```

and this is the error that I'm getting

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is being caused by receiving no imported methods from routers.js. Make sure your file names and directories are correct. With app.js in the root directory and routers.js in /routers, everything looks fine and worked when I ran it locally.

Also, since you're setting the path for "/users" in both app.js and routers.js, the actual path being used is "/users/users". Assuming this wasn't intended, I would suggest removing the path parameter from one of those methods.